# How to use redis client in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, microservices, nestjs

I have a microservice in NestJs, here is the main.ts file:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
      url: 'redis://localhost:6379',
    }
  })
  await app.listen();
  console.log('Redis is running');
}
bootstrap();
```

I want to make calls to redis db from the service:

```
import { createClient } from '@redis/client';

async createWorkspaceShareCode(data: GetWorkspaceShareCodeMessage) {
    const client = createClient({
      url: 'redis://localhost:6379'
    });
    await client.connect();

    await client.set('key', 'value');
    const value = await client.get('key');
    return value;
  }
```

But that's not what I want, here are the issues:

- every time I make request, it creates new connection
- I need to write this code in each function to connect to redis (even though I'm already connected in main.ts file)
  Here is the question: how can I use some kind of RedisService in my NestJs microservice?
  I have already tried installing redis and nestjs-redis libraries, but the first one creates the issue described above and the second one just throws me an error: https://github.com/skunight/nestjs-redis/issues/97

Comment: Isn't this two different use cases for redis? One for listening to events and responding to them (from the `createMicroservice` call) and one for using Redis as a key:value database (from the `nestjs-redis` or `createClient` call)?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, sure it is, I just wanted to try both

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I would do is keep your `createMicroservice` as you have it as it'll be necessary for a Redis-based microservice server. Then you can create a module that exports a Redis service like so:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'REDIS_OPTIONS',
      useValue: {
        url: 'redis://localhost:6379'
      }
    },
    {
      inject: ['REDIS_OPTIONS']
      provide: 'REDIS_CLIENT',
      useFactory: async (options: { url: string }) => {
        const client = createClient(options);
        await client.connect();
        return client;
      }
    }
  ],
  exports: ['REDIS_CLIENT'],
})
export class RedisModule {}
```

Now in the module that contains the service you want to use add `RedisModule` to the `imports` array and in the service you can do `@Inject('REDIS_CLIENT') private readonly redis: Redis` to inject the Redis instance and use it with `this.redis.get('key')` and `this.redis.set('key', value)`
we can import "Redis" from 'ioredis' library. It works perfectly fine. To summarize, we need both `redis` and `ioredis` libraries. `redis` for `createClient` and `ioredis` library for Redis.

```
1. import { createClient } from "redis";<br>
2. import { Redis } from 'ioredis';
```

Comment: While injecting, Where is the type definition for `redis` coming from in the line below?
`@Inject('REDIS_CLIENT') private readonly redis: Redis`

Comment: If you're using the [node-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) package, it looks like it should be `RedisClientType`. I think I wrote this example for redis v3 instead of v4. Another option would be to use `ioredis` which has more straighforward typings

Comment: Found it, It should be `RedisClientType<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts>`. Thanks.

Comment: I using redis client like this, but encountered an issue when trying to implement healthchecks for my services. When redis goes down for some reason it will just start logging errors in console and the app will hang until it gets back up. And idea how do do some popper error handling using this approach?